# Is there other way to hide the password in textbox (***) aside from textboxmode="password"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

It seems like if I use `TextMode="password"`it changes the size of the textbox and also the placeholder text style. It doesn't match the other textboxes that I made. Although it does the work for me, just curious if there is another way to make it happen to avoid ruining the design. Thanks!

```
<div class="form-group" style= "float:left">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPW" runat="server" name="form-password-name"  Width="200px" 
         placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" 
         TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" 
         ErrorMessage="Only letters and numbers are allowed" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtPW" 
         ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$">  
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
                                ErrorMessage="Password is required." ControlToValidate="txtPW" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
</div>
```

Comment: Look into it : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18087/ASP-NET-Password-TextBox

Comment: show us your css, maybe there is something incorrect there.

Comment: Normally `textboxmode="password"` does not change the appearance of the textbox. What is `form-password` css style do?

Comment: oh i see. its weird i removed the form-password, nothing changed.

Comment: That maybe help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466248/asp-net-textbox-size-differs-when-textmode-password or http://forums.asp.net/t/1913278.aspx?Any+known+IE10+issues+with+textboxes+

Answer (score 1):

you can use a regular html textbox:

```
<input type="password" name="form-password-name" id="txtPW" class="form-password form-control"/>
```

Comment: im using asp:textbox sir@Fahad Jameel